# Blank custom file input using bootstrap4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, input, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement the custom-file-input using bootstrap4 alpha 6, but I get blank section after adding it, as following:

```
<label class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" id="file" class="custom-file-input">
    <span class="custom-file-control"></span>
</label>
```

[Bootstrap4 file browser documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#file-browser)

[image: Blank file input]

Is there's any CSS style that I should add with this implementation?

Comment: @ZimSystem I have already mentioned one above !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the docs, the placeholder and button are set in CSS:

```
.custom-file-control::after {
  content: "Select file...";
}

.custom-file-control::before {
  content: "Click me";
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/jcnmleDWja

Also, you can use a language declaration in the HTML doc. For example,

`<html lang="en"></html>`

and set specific style for each language...

```
.custom-file-control:lang(en)::after {
  content: "Select file...";
}

.custom-file-control:lang(en)::before {
  content: "Click me";
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/jcnmleDWja